# How to convert time variable as continuous numeric variable in R

Tags: r

I got a data formatted file that contains date variables, which are formatted as, for example, 9/28/2017 16:00. I want to turn these variables into continuous numeric variables like 16 in this case (Others like 9/28/2017 17:00 to 17 and 9/30/2017 17:00 to 17 as well). I only want the times no matter what date it is. How could I do that in R?

Comment: A timestamp such as `"9/28/2017 16:00"` can easily be converted into a `POSIXt` object (R's atomic timestamp class) using `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`, I'd think a format of `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` should suffice, timezone notwithstanding. From there, if you use `as.numeric` on the `POSIXt` objects, it will convert to seconds epoch (e.g., `1506614400` for that timestamp, using `UTC` as the input tz, lacking anything else). To extract one component from that can be done with various methods, including `as.POSIXlt(time1)$hour` if you'd like (noting the `lt` instead of `ct`).

Comment: While you may only *want* the hours in those timestamps, I suggest you become at least passably familiar with the whole timestamp process so that you can more adeptly work with them; taking shortcuts that don't do this might work, but there are enough corner-cases (e.g., daylight savings, leap-years) where doing any comparison between your "hours" might not always reflect the truth from the original timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

One way of extracting the `hour` part of the data is to use `gsub`:

```
y <- as.POSIXct(c("9/28/2017 16:00", "9/28/2017 17:00"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
y
#[1] "2017-09-28 16:00:00 +07" "2017-09-28 17:00:00 +07" 
#Here +7 is my timezone. 

as.numeric(gsub("(.*?)\\s|\\:00*", "",y))
#[1] 16 17
```

It also works in case the "date" has character type.

```
z <- "9/28/2017 16:00"
str(z)
#chr "9/28/2017 16:00"
as.numeric(gsub("(.*?)\\s|\\:00*", "",z))
#[1] 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to use the `lubridate` package. Here is a `tidyverse` solution; the basic idea is to first change the date elements to a date-time type (I do this with `lubridate::mdy_hms`), and then from there, use the `lubridate::hour` function to extract the hour that you want. You could also use the `hms::as_hms` function in lieu of the `lubridate::hour` function if you needed more information about the time.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

## creating an example tibble (dataframe) with two example dates
example_df <- tribble(~date, "9/28/2017 16:00", "9/28/2017 17:00")

## changing the date column to an date_time first, then extract hour from there in two different ways
## the first way uses lubridate::hour the second uses hms::as_hms
example_df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(date)) %>% 
  mutate(hour = hour(date)) %>% 
  mutate(hour_minute = hms::as_hms(date))
```